# How to find minimum signed value in array in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

i am trying to make selection sort program in assembly but i stuck how to find minimum signed number

i am beginner in assembly i learned just conditional and unconditional jumps and subroutines

i have assignment of selection sort of array of signed numbers i write code it finds minimum number but after further comparison it store greater number

```
[org 0x0100] 
          jmp  start 

data:          dw   -1,-7,0,-4
temp:          dw 0

start:
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,4
    mov ax,[data+bx]
h1;
    cmp ax,[data+bx+2]
    jnle l1 

    add bx,2
    cmp bx,6
    jne h1




l1:
    mov dx,[data+bx+2]
    mov [temp],dx
    add bx,2
    cmp bx,6
    jne h1

    mov  ax, 0x4c00         
        int  0x21
```

i expect after termination of my program array will be sorted according to following the selection sort algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm doesn't make much sense. Your current code would correspond to something like this in C:

```
int min = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (data[i] > data[i+1]) {
        min = data[i+1];
    }
}
```

Note how your comparison doesn't take the current `min` value into account. It only cares about the difference between adjacent elements in the array (and those elements do not move around in the loop).

---

What you *should* be doing is something like this:

```
int min = data[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    if (data[i] < min) {
        min = data[i];
    }
}
```

It should be simple enough for you to translate that into assembly.

Comment: thanks i already did with my code now i am stuck somewhere else